# Magento table rates not working

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods, table-rates

On our Magento website we have set free shipping for all orders over €50 but have noticed that sometimes it does not work.  I've been testing it and it seems to work when I tried it on orders over €62 & €69.  But it did not work for orders of €50 €53.50, €55, €58.50, €59.95, €60.

Euro is our base currency.  I've tried re-indexing and clearing the cache.

These are our settings...
[image]

I tried changing the order sub-total value to €49.99 from €50 but that did not help at all.

```
ABW *   *   0   30
ABW *   *   49.99   0
AFG *   *   0   30
AFG *   *   49.99   0
AGO *   *   0   30
AGO *   *   49.99   0
AIA *   *   0   30
AIA *   *   49.99   0
ALA *   *   0   30
ALA *   *   49.99   0
ALB *   *   0   30
ALB *   *   49.99   0
AND *   *   0   30
AND *   *   49.99   0
ANT *   *   0   30
ANT *   *   49.99   0
ARE *   *   0   30
ARE *   *   49.99   0
ARG *   *   0   30
ARG *   *   49.99   0
ARM *   *   0   30
ARM *   *   49.99   0
ASM *   *   0   30
ASM *   *   49.99   0
ATA *   *   0   30
ATA *   *   49.99   0
ATF *   *   0   30
ATF *   *   49.99   0
ATG *   *   0   30
ATG *   *   49.99   0
AUS *   *   0   20
AUS *   *   49.99   0
AUT *   *   0   12.5
AUT *   *   49.99   0
```

I also tried it again with a new table rates file for just one country.

```
Country Region/State    Zip/Postal Code Order Subtotal (and above)  Shipping Price
IRL *   *   0   6
IRL *   *   50  0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like this could be related to taxes, do you have a tax rate set?

If you do (which the default i think is 20%) then I believe the import should be without tax which means if you have included the prices with tax, it's taking your €50, adding 20% tax which makes it €60.

To solve it you could work out what the price would be without tax and put that in your csv, or you may need to extend the core functionality to ignore tax, around line 78 (i think) in

```
Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Tablerate.php
```

Comment: that was it `:)` nicely thought of.  Our tax is 23% so I just calculated it should be €40.65. Thanks